# Workbox Warming Cache Questions

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have  api's that I am caching in my app. I would like to cache the api while the service worker is installing. I came across warming the cache:

```
import {cacheNames} from 'workbox-core';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const urls = [/* ... */];
  const cacheName = cacheNames.runtime;
  event.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => cache.addAll(urls)));
});
```

> If you use strategies configured with a custom cache name you can do the same thing; just assign your custom value to cacheName.

1) I am using custom cache names. Would I use an array for multiple cache names? ie `const cacheName = [ 'foo-api', 'bar'api']`?

2) The url's I use are regexp `/foo/`. Will those rexexp urls work here?

3) Will I be able to cache the api while the service worker is installing before the browser consumes the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many items to as many caches as you'd like inside of your `install` handler.

Workbox can use `RegExp`s for routing incoming `fetch` requests to an appropriate response handler, and I assume that's what you're referring to here. The answer is no, you can't just provide a `RegExp` if you want to cache URLs in advance—you need to provide a complete list of URLs.

Any caching that you perform inside of an `install` handler is guaranteed to happen before the service worker activates, and therefore before your `fetch` handlers start intercepting requests. So yes, this is a way of ensuring that your caches are pre-populated.

A modification of your code could look like:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const cacheURLs = async () => {
    const cache1 = await caches.open('my-first-cache');
    await cache1.addAll([
      '/url1',
      '/url2',
    ]);

    const cache2 = await caches.open('my-second-cache');
    await cache2.addAll([
      '/url3',
      '/url4',
    ]);
  };

  event.waitUntil(cacheURLs());
});
```

Comment: What if the urls are RESTful apis with dynamic parameters and I need to regexp? like `/customer/1/item/5`?

Comment: That's not how caching things in advance works. You need to provide a list of URLs. Think about it like this—what is the source of the URLs that the `RegExp` is supposed to match, if you don't provide them?